# Fluent Bit only receiving logs on first connection

Tags: serilog, fluent-bit

I'm trying to use Serilog (the [Serilog.Sinks.Network](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/Serilog.Sinks.Network) sink) to write to a Fluentbit instance (just running locally).

I'm finding that if I start Fluentbit, then run my app, the logs get processed as expected. However, without restarting Fluentbit, if I then run my app subsequent times, the logs no longer appear. Restarting Fluentbit will go back to making it work again (but again, just that first time). I'm not seeing any errors (even with Fluentbit turned up to trace logging).

[image]

The above code is here incase it's useful:
https://github.com/dracan/FluentBitProblem

I'm seeing similar issues when trying other Serilog Sinks too - eg. [Serilog.Sinks.Fluentd](https://github.com/borisermakof/serilog-sinks-fluentd). Feels like there's something I'm missing with the way FluentBit connections work.

## A bit more information

Digging a bit further, and getting out Wireshark - I can see that the TCP data is being sent for both the working and failing attempts...

[image]
[image]

If I use a bogus port number, Wireshark recognised this...

[image]

And if I log in a while loop, and then kill the Fluentbit process - Wireshark also picks this up as an error...

[image]

[image]

Which suggests to me that Fluentbit is getting the logs, but ignoring them for some reason.